# Is there a way to program macros to finely tune animations in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: animation, macros, libreoffice

After long research, I came upon [this only module](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1presentation.html#a10f2a3114ab31c0e6f7dc48f656fd260), which would allow to tune animations for the shapes in LibreOffice Impress via macros, but it is very limited. I need, for example, to be able to create shapes with defined motions paths, to be able to set "Accelerated start" and "Decelerated end" options, control duration, delays, etc. You can do that manually, but cannot via macros. Has anyone managed to overcome this limitation?